# Is research related to "the fold" in web design age-contingent?

Tags: website-design, wireframe

I recently encountered an argument that, while the fold may be commonly touted as bad UX by web designers, that anyone over the age of 60 will still succumb to the effect, and will not think to scroll for additional content.

I am curious to see what research says about this. Is the fold still relevant for certain age groups? Everyone is familiar with "Life Below 600px", but did those studies stratify their samples demographically?

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'The Fold' is still a relevant consideration for design in general.

In many usability tests I have run, many users, without visual cues can have difficulty with scrolled content. That can be along any axis income, device, contextual familiarity, not just age. In many of my designs, especially if using a large hero, visual indication might not be the sexiest, but does help users to find content below the fold.

Also, the fold is still relevant in information hierarchy design. Things that exist visibly when a user first comes to a site must be the most important information because for any age group, it will be treated as such. If users don't like what they see above the fold, why would they scroll below the fold.

Some references:
http://www.nngroup.com/articles/page-fold-manifesto/
http://alistapart.com/article/whoneedsheadlines